# Are there any static analysis tools that will report how closely the SOLID principles are followed?

Tags: static-analysis, solid-principles

I know blindly following any "best practice" can still lead to a stinking pile of crap that strictly adheres to the best practice. The SOLID principles are just that, *principles*. They don't apply to every situation but they are still very good heuristics for finding possible improvements in your code.

The downside to them is that they sometimes require a deep analysis of your source code to apply them. I, like most programmers, am constantly on the lookout for more efficient ways of doing things. So, I am curious if anyone has heard of an analysis tool that attempts to test for the application of SOLID principles (or lack thereof).

> **SRP**  *The Single Responsibility
>   Principle*
>
> A class should have only one reason to
>   change.
>
> **OCP**  *The Open-Closed
>   Principle*
>
> Software entities (classes, modules,
>   functions, etc.) should be open for
>   extension, but closed for
>   modification.
>
> **LSP**  *The Liskov
>   Substitution Principle*
>
> Subtypes must be substitutable for
>   their base types.
>
> **ISP**  *The Interface
>   Segregation Principle*
>
> Clients should not be forced to depend
>   upon methods that they do not use.
>   Interfaces belong to clients, not to
>   hierarchies.
>
> **DIP**  *The
>   Dependency Inversion Principle*
>
> Abstractions should not depend upon
>   details. Details should depend upon
>   abstractions.

-From *Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices* by Robert C. Martin.

Comment: *The downside to them is that they sometime require a deep analysis of your source code to apply them.* If an analysis of the code (regardless how deep) would suffice, such tools would be possible, however looking into the code is not enough.

Comment: @Wolf In the context of that particular sentence I meant a _human_ analysis based on understanding, insight and intuition.

Comment: You mean patterns that are retrieved from human code analysis whose presence are later checked in an automated way?

Comment: No. I was simply asking if there were any tools that could come close to approximating the results achieved by manual analysis of code by a skilled software developer. I think the top answer summed it up pretty well. Such tools don't exist because the SOLID principles are too informal for automated analysis.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that automatic static analysis can determine if the principles are respected. To write such a tool you'd need to define formally what each concept means and have a way to check it against any code. How would you formalize the notion of a responsibility? I have personally no idea.

That said, you can have tools to help you detect the likelihood of violation. 
For example you could use code metrics such as number of methods per class, number of members per class to determine if a class is too big and therefore likely to violate SRP.

An exception might be the Liskov Substitution Principle. 
**IF** you define the contracts on all the methods (preconditions, postconditions, invariants) then you can check that a method redefining a method of a superclass don't strengthen the precondition, don't weaken the postcondition and respect the invariants of the superclass's method. I think that the tool [ESC/Java](http://secure.ucd.ie/products/opensource/ESCJava2/) performs those checks. 
Reading the [wikipedia page about LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) more checks would have to be performed.

Answer (score 4):

My answer involves a .NET-specific product, apologies in advance, and maybe someone can suggest its non-.NET analogs.

I'd give [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx) a try and see if it can lead me to the violations of SRP and ISP by using metrics like:

- number of methods per type types with
- abnormally high numbers of methods
- afferent/efferent coupling at the assembly and type level
- other metrics, [full list of metrics here](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx)

DIP and LSP violations may be harder to track down because they involve the programmer's intent.  An analysis tool can identify the relationship between types, but how can it tell a situation where one class genuinely extends another from Square's inappropriately deriving from Rectangle?  Or, that in a properly designed program, A should have depended on B and not the other way around?

OCP presents a different challenge because the extension/modification that the class should be open/closed to may not necessarily have already taken place.

However, if we believe that following SOLID leads to a more maintainable product (proving this claim scientifically is not what this question is about), then NDepend's Abstractness-Instability chart should give a good **aggregate** measure of how well the principles were followed for each software module.  If they were, the module should have avoided the bottom-left corner of the chart, dubbed "The Zone of Pain".  In that zone, the module is stable (not in a good way -- too many others depend on it, so it's difficult to change), but not abstract enough.

Comment: In theory, if a programmer had put a set of perfect tests around each object, would it be possible to automatically detect a Liskov violation? 

Taking the square isA rectangle case, where square’s setWidth() and setHeight() methods have the side effect of setting not only the declared variable, but also the other. E.g. setWidth updates not only the width, but the height. setHeight updates both the width and the height (cont in next comment)

Comment: This is a behavioral Liskov violation that would not be able to be detected without a test. However, if the Rectangle class had a test enforcing setWidth() updates width and does not change height, running Square through the Rectangle’s unit tests would yield a failure. 

In a language like Java, you could write a program that would take all the child instances of a parent class and run the parent’s tests over them. 

That would capture side effect violations and likely additional errors being thrown.

Comment: Clarification on "perfect" in "perfect tests" above: I don't mean it would take all sets of possible inputs and outputs, but "enough" (which is a very squishy word). Perhaps this means 1 example of setWidth() to be 100 that would represent all positive integers.