# How to check whether my app following S.O.L.I.D. Principle

Tags: java, android, kotlin, solid-principles

I have created one app in kotlin, I tried to follow all OOPS and [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles in my app. But after development of whole app i want to check whether any class is missing or breaking rules of SOLID principle.

Try 1

Review the whole code in each class whether they are following SOLID principles or not. But if i have large number of files then it will take more time.

How can we do it automatically to check whether my app is following SOLID principles.

Comment: Related question, might offer some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627024/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-that-will-report-how-closely-the-solid-princ

Comment: SOLID principles are not **rules**, they are principles to use to inform or improve your design.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check it with an automatic tool. The concepts of S.O.L.I.D. principles cannot be converted in formulas to be calculated automatically.

Just to have an idea. The I means [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle):

> ... **ISP splits interfaces that are very large into smaller and more specific ones** so that clients will only have to know about the methods that are of interest to them

How much an interface should be small? Who decides if two methods are related to the same concept so they can not be separated in different interfaces? There is no way to do that automatically

Let's consider another principle. The [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

> ... the "inversion" concept does not mean that lower-level layers depend on higher-level layers directly. **Both layers should depend on abstractions (interfaces) that expose the behavior needed by higher-level layers**.

Basically you should depends on interfaces instead of concrete classes. But what happens if you are using an external library that doesn't use interfaces? Your code is correct, but is not following the Dependency Inversion Principle so you will have a false negative in this case.

Similar considerations can be done also for other principles.

Comment: https://www.ndepend.com/
But it is only available in .NET